# Xcode simulator for iPhone has square black image when Run

Tags: iphone, swift, ios-simulator

I spent the last 4 hours going over this issue in stackOverFlow which many have had faced. But none of the solutions given worked for me. My issue is that when I run iPhone simulator on Xcode, I see a small black image overlaying my interface. And I could not get rid of it, Strangely for iPad simulator and if I run any other project I don't see the black image in my simulator. Using Xcode 7.0.1 Screenshot Attached.

I have gone over the solutions like emptying the launch screen file, deleting derived data, adding the default .png image and resetting simulator. None worked. Can you please help me on this issue. Why this black image comes up ? What causes it. [Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvpbf.png)

Comment: Is it possible you're adding a black subview somewhere in your app? Try using the [Xcode View Debugger](http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6) to track it down.

Comment: I removed all the views and ran the simulator yet the black image still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

UIImage view appeared separately from the image I added to the project. And both views were like separate objects resulting in this issue. I re-worked the entire storyboard again to resolve issue.